# Remove HTML select dropdown if no options exist

Tags: html, css

I would like to remove dropdown options list when `select` element is empty. This happens on Windows / Chrome where it shows an empty dropdown with box shadow around it. Is there a CSS way to achieve this?

I can't use `disabled` attribute as I have some events attached on clicking the empty select. Also I don't wish to hide the select.

```css
select {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<select name="test" id="test"></select>
```

Comment: Well you can set `disabled="true"` when there are no options available(use a little bit js to check if it has no options)  or even you can hide the select box conditionally when there شقث no options available I mean what's the point of showing an empty select option anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Use `empty` in CSS

```css
select:empty {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<select></select>
```

Here's the one when the `select` **IS NOT** disabled:

```css
select:empty {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Hello World!</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I wish to still show the select, just hiden the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if pointer events are set to none then JS events won't work. Also no option should be present, select must be empty.

Comment: @g5wx that's impossible and it's different for some browsers.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that it happens on Win Chrome only. Macos Chrome works fine so I tought there could be some CSS hack for this.